# Does path connectedness of $Cl(A)$ implies $A$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I recently came across a problem in which it was necessary to prove that $\mathbb Q^2 \cup \mathbb I^2$ is connected but and I went through the path connectivity of $Cl(\mathbb Q^2 \cup \mathbb I^2)$. I heard about this fact from friends, but I still couldn't prove it. Now there are no ideas

So does path connectedness of $Cl(A)$ implies $A$ is connected?

Comment: In general, $Cl(A)$ path connected does not imply that $A$ is connected. Take for example $(0,1)$ without a point.

Comment: Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg oh you're right, I'm sorry

Comment: To show that the space is connected, it suffices to show that every non-trivial open set has a boundary point, the reason being, if an open set has a boundary point, it is not closed, and hence every non trivial open set is not closed, which is an [equivalent characterisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) of connected spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is of course not true. The closure of $[0,2] \setminus \{1\}$ in the real line is path connected, but the set itself is not connected.

Comment: Thank you. I don't even understand how I missed such a simple example

Answer (score 2):

You can say that if $A$ is connected, then any $B$ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq Cl(A)$ is connected. Also, if $A$ is path connected, then $A$ is connected, hence $Cl(A)$ is connected. But you cannot claim that path connectedness of $Cl(A)$ implies connectedness of $A$, as others have stated.